# Safari content editable div text dissapears

Tags: svg, text, safari

I am seeing a strange issue in Safari 10 that may be present in earlier versions. When SVG content is present in the document along with a content editable div the text is disappearing. This happens mostly when selecting text, but also while toggling the display property of the svg content. Here are a few videos showing the behavior: http://www.screencast.com/t/CeyFqYyfeFZW
http://www.screencast.com/t/eRAGsopA

I can't make the application available publicly. We have a pretty complex document composition layer which is probably to blame. I'll try posting an isolated test later. I have only observed this issue on Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.05). iOS seems to be fine.  If anyone has seen this issue before please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I created an isolated test here: https://jsfiddle.net/gr1redv6/1/ . Clicking on any of the editable divs causes them to disappear until you use the scroll bar. I assume this resets focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of tests I figured out that in this particular example the problem is caused by the situation when editable text has higher z-index than image (raster or svg). Image can be placed anywhere, but not geometrically below the text. This issue also is specific to Safari 10+. Testing the original example in 9.1 everything works.

I have created a simple example testing `z-index` https://jsfiddle.net/xngmocxm/9/
There is a background element, which is jpeg, it has z-index = 0, 2 svg path elements (grey and red), 2 editable text elements and svg image (HomeSmart in the top left corner).
Z-index of the left text element is set to 30, right one has z-index 20, svg image z-index is set to 25, i.e. in between 2 text elements. In test browser I can see that in this case only the left text disappears, right one is shown and selected just fine.
So the svg that is above the text does not manifest the issue, but if the SVG is below the editable text this issue occurs.
If image content is jpeg, it also causes same issue:
`img src` https://jsfiddle.net/xngmocxm/12/

Anyway I was able to fix this by setting overflow to hidden on image wrapper of the problematic image element. I think this a is Safari bug and not intentional behavior.